# how to use puppeteer in selenium automation testing for head less chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, puppeteer

If any one knows, what is puppeteer and how to use this in selenium automation for headless chrome please guide me.

Below is the link for puppeteer.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

1) can i use this with java language for automation testing?

2) what is the use of using this?

I am new to this puppeteer and I wanted to use this in my project which is built on java and selenium.

Comment: First line in the docs: "Puppeteer is a Node library ..." So that sounds like a "No" for your Java question. Maybe describe your problem, instead of your broken solution. Also have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 8):

Puppeteer is replacement for selenium running only on Chrome. It's not possible to run puppeteer from selenium. Puppeteer is designed only for chrome and run only in Node.js environment. If you are interested in running chrome headless from selenium this [thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324&q=component%3AInternals%3EHeadless&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) can be valuable for you.

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium Headless execution you can use following code or watch video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNZSLYkTBSE

Initialize driver with option

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("Headless");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Linking your own YouTube video is fine, as long as it is to support a relevant answer, but you *must disclose affiliation in the post* when linking to something you're affiliated with. If you don't disclose affiliation, it can be considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)